# $\mathbb{P}^1$ is separated

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'd like to understand why $\mathbb{P}^1$ is separated. The definition of separated I'm using is that for a prevariety $X$ (a ringed space covered by a finite number of affine varieties) the diagonal $D_X=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$ is closed $X$. My idea is to use the universal property of products to get a morphism $F$ from $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ and then use the fact that $\mathbb{A}^1$ is separated. Now, I know that every morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$ is necessarily constant, and so every map from $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto (c,d)$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb{A}^1$. But this doesn't seem to work, since if $c=d$, then $F^{-1}(D_{\mathbb{A}^1})$ is $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ and if $c\neq d$, then $F^{-1}(D_{\mathbb{A}^1})$ is empty. In either case, we can say nothing about the diagonal of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Is there a better way to approach this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's a different strategy: can you show the diagonal $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is a closed embedding? In other words, are there equations that cut out the diagonal?

Comment: Regarding your original strategy, I'm not sure if one can get much out of these constant maps to $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$.